# How to ask to crank or turn the music down?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, gramática

I've been doing a search lately but haven't found anything about that. How is it said?

Not merely "***La musica está demasiado alta o ruidosa***", but a request: "***can you crank/turn the music down a bit?***"

Comment: Why are you saying crank instead of turn down? Usually, we crank up music or heat or air conditioning or some kind of motor.  Crank down is not common at all. Where did you hear that? So, you are asking a question about something that is not said in English.

Comment: @Lambie what's difference: crank down/turn down?

Comment: We don't say ***crank down***, usually.  We say ***crank up: the heat, the air conditioning, the music and motors. Crank up is idiomatic.*** Crank down for this context does  not exist. That's why I asked you where you saw it or heard it. The only thing one ***might crank down*** is some sort of machine (levers,machines, ladders, etc) that have ***a crank***. It is not used metaphorically.

Comment: @lambie - I've heard "crank it down."  In fact, here's an NIH article with that title!  https://www.nidcd.nih.gov/newsletter/2006/summer/crank-it-down

Comment: @nylypej - Also: *bajar el volumen*.

Comment: @aparente001 The article is using it on purpose ***to be ironic***. It is not usual, and that's exactly why as used in that title, it is good. Otherwise, it would not be.

Comment: @Lambie - I guess some people use it ironically, and some people don't realize it started out ironic when used for turning something down.  This might make an interesting question at ELU!

Comment: @aparente001 It did not start out as ironic. [sigh]. It started out as "crank up", an actual action [ha ha] in an industrial or automotive (early cars had cranks) context. If you crank up the heat in your house, it means you were cold and the temperature was very low (say, 30 degrees F) and you set the heat to: 78 degrees F in one go. The opposite action (very hot to cooler with AC) is not known as crank down. And that's why it's funny and eye- and ear-catching.

Comment: @Lambie - I'll try to be clearer.  Originally, the verb was used for turning things waaay up.  Agreed.  Then somebody had the bright idea of using it for the opposite, and maybe they were trying to be cute.  That's what I was trying to say with the word "ironic."  Eventually it ended up being used by people to mean *turn something down," without realizing that they weren't using it right.  If you google this phrase ("crank down" or "crank it down") you'll see that it's taken off.  We can't blame people for using it that way, if they picked it up from others.

Comment: @aparente001 Let's stop this,shall we? You are mistaken. Sorry. crank down is not used and that title is a strong precisely for that reason and no other. Were it not not used, the title would be silly. And Google just picks up junk; google can't "tell you anything".  There are other examples: speed up, hurry up, finish up. We don't say: speed down, hurry down [as the opposite of hurry up], or finish down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request `can you crank the music down (a bit)?` would be

> ¿Puedes bajar la música (un poco)?

in "Tú" form. In "Usted" form it is:

> ¿Puede bajar la música (un poco)?

Comment: and how to ask to make it louder?

Comment: The problem is no one really says crank down the music. You ***crank up air-conditioning, heating, motors, and music***. Not crank down.

Comment: ¿Como se puede traduzir algo que en el outro idioma no se diría?

Comment: @nylypej  make it louder uses the opposite of "bajar", which is "subir". Same sentence but changing "bajar" for "subir".

Comment: @Lambie that doesn't make sense

Comment: Of course,it does.Turn down the music is bajar la música. Crank down the music is a no-go. No se diría crank down the music.

Answer (score 2):

A rude neighbor, or your parents if you're a teen, merely yell at you:

> ¡¡ESA MÚSICA!!

Comment: es MAGNIFICAAAAA!!!

Comment: That's it! We hear this quite often. Welcome to the site, Afilla

Comment: What I yell to my teen: "¡AUDÍFONOS!"